# TypeScript の型の付け方について

Tags: typescript

以下のようなコードを書いています。

```js
export default function hogeStore()  {
  const getters = {
    get huga() {
    }
  }

  return { getters }
}
```

利用側で `hogeStore().getters.huga` とすると

```
Property 'getters' does not exist on type 'unknown'.
```

というエラーが出ます。

正しく型をつけるにはどのように書けばよいでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 関数 hogeStoreに返り値が設定されていないのでは？

Comment: 記述漏れでした。追加しました。

Comment: "Property 'getters' does not exist on type 'unknown'. というエラーが出ます。"、再現しませんし、エラーがどこにどのタイミングで出るか? という情報がないです。

Answer (score 0):

あなたのコードではローカルな定数`getters`を作成していますが、その定数は使用しないまま戻り値が何もない状態で関数`hogeStore()`が終了しています。戻り値を返していないので、その値は`undefined`、`undefined`には`getters`なんてプロパティはありませんからエラーになっています。

戻り値を返せば、その戻り値を利用できます。

```
export default function hogeStore() {
  const getters = {
    get huga() {
       ...
    }
  }
  return getters; //<-
}

var result = hogeStore().huga;
```

どうしても、`hogeStore().getters.huga`という風に呼び出しがしたいなら、

```
export default function hogeStore() {
  const getters = {
    get huga() {
       ...
    }
  }
  return {getters: getters}; //<-
}

var result = hogeStore().getters.huga;
```

などと書けるでしょう。

Comment: すみません、return { getters } の行を記述し忘れていました。
追加しました。

Comment: @おれんじ さん、残念ながら追加後のコードだとこちらでは、`Property 'getters' does not exist on type 'unknown'.`というエラーは再現できませんでした。エラーの情報は本当に正しいものですか？